# Clear d3.js charts before loading new chart

Tags: svg, d3.js, charts

I am using d3.js to display charts with some sensor data. When I select a new sensor and click submit, I want to clear the already existing charts and display the newly selected one.

I have tried variations of `d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg").remove();` and the problem I encounter is that when I press submit it clears the charts right away and displays nothing.

I have a d3helper file, which does all of the d3 functions:

```
function initD3Chart( chartName, chartId, xAxisType, interpolate, width, height, yLabel ) {

// Size and margins
var m = [30, 60, 40, 20],// Margins
    w = width - m[1] - m[3],
    h = height - m[0] - m[2];
x = d3.time.scale().range([0, w]);
x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, w]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSize(-h, 0).tickPadding(6).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H: &M"));
var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSize(-15, 1).tickPadding(-12).ticks(d3.time.day, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B %d, %Y"));

// An area generator.
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate(interpolate)
    .defined(function(d) { return (!isNaN(d.v0) && !isNaN(d.v1)); })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.p); })
    //.x2(function(d) { return x(d.r);})
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.u1); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.v1); });

// A line generator.
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate(interpolate)
    .defined(function(d) { return (!isNaN(d.v1)); })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.p); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.v1); });

// Attach root visualization node to div.#vis
var svg = d3.select("#vis")
    .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("class", chartId)
        .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
        .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
    .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

// Clip overflow
    svg.append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", x(0))
            .attr("x2", x2(0))
            .attr("y", y(1))
            .attr("width", x(1) - x(0))
            .attr("height", y(0) - y(1));

// Y Axis
svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w + ",0)");

// X Axis
svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")");

svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h + 30) + ")");

// Chartarea. Where plots will be appended
chart = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "chartarea");

// Interaction area
var rect = svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "pane")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

return {
            "id": chartId,
            "svg": svg,
            "chart": chart,
            "rect": rect,
            "x": x,
            "x2": x2,
            "y": y,
            "xAxis": xAxis,
            "xAxis2": xAxis2,
            "yAxis": yAxis,
            "line": line,
            "area": area,
            "w": w,
            "h": h,
            "m": m
        };
    }
```

I have a submit button, which when clicked takes all the data from the form and initializes the chart title etc., and does the appropriate AJAX calls.
In my init file I call the d3 functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        for(var j = 0, n = sensor.length; j < n; j++)
        {
            var callback = {
                "id": "idGoesHere"
            };

            var chart = drawDataView ( callback );

            callback.dataLoaded = function(chart) {
                return function( total, remaining ) {
                    chart.redraw();
                };  
            }(chart);
        }
        //When selecting a new sensor remove the previous sensor from the array or it draws an additional graph
        sensor.length = 0;

        d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg").remove();
    });         
}); 


function drawDataView(callback){    
    var vis = initD3Chart( demo['name'], demo['id'], demo['xAxis'], demo['interpolate'], width, height, yLabel );
    vis['x'].domain([timeToDate(displayRange.lower), timeToDate(displayRange.upper)]);
    vis['x2'].domain([timeToDate(displayRange.lower), timeToDate(displayRange.upper)]);
    vis['y'].domain( demo['yDomain'] ); // Default, will be set when first data loaded
    vis['rect'].call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(vis['x']).on("zoom", update));
    vis['rect'].call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(vis['x2']).on("zoom", update));
}
function redraw() {    
    // Update Axes
    vis['svg'].select("g.x.axis").call(vis['xAxis']);
    vis['svg'].select("g.x.axis2").call(vis['xAxis2']).selectAll("text").attr("x", 48);
    vis['svg'].select("g.y.axis").call(vis['yAxis']);
}
```

Is there a way to do both?

Comment: Show us more code. What does your redraw code look like? Is it recreating the svg element (that you are removing) or is it trying to append to an element that doesn't exist?

Comment: @TysonAnderson: Edited with code. Sorry, I was unsure what to include in the beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling for the removal after you've drawn the new chart. So just move some things:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {

        //When selecting a new sensor remove the previous sensor from the array or it draws an additional graph
        sensor.length = 0;

        d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg").remove();

        for(var j = 0, n = sensor.length; j < n; j++)
        {
            var callback = {
                "id": "idGoesHere"
            };

            var chart = drawDataView ( callback );

            callback.dataLoaded = function(chart) {
                return function( total, remaining ) {
                    chart.redraw();
                };  
            }(chart);
        }

    });         
});
```

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot, thanks! I only need to move `d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg").remove();` above the for loop. Moving `sensor.length=0` empties the array before I can draw anything

Comment: You probably should use exit() remove() if you're reusing the same chart type, anyway.

Comment: I was just thinking preventing possible memory leaks but when I tried `d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg").exit().remove();` it said that exit is not a function. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To use exit you need a broader pattern.. Enter, exit, update.